# Google Test in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, googletest

I am trying to get started with unit testing. I downloaded the latest build of gtest, and extracted it to `A:\gtest` As the instructions specified, I opened gtest.sln. Visual studio only allows me to open the sln if I agree to update it. Then when I try to build I get a pile of errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: gtest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  gtest-all.cc
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\gtest-printers.h(550): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\gtest-printers.h(558): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4017): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4249) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::CartesianProductGenerator9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>' being compiled
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4017): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4017): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4017): error C2955: 'testing::internal::ParamGeneratorInterface' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util.h(142) : see declaration of 'testing::internal::ParamGeneratorInterface'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4019): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4030): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4030): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4035): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4035): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4042): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4042) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::CartesianProductGenerator9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>::Iterator' being compiled
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4042): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4042): error C2955: 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util.h(69) : see declaration of 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4044): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4044): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4077): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4077): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4119): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4119): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4123): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4123): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4204): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4204): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4256): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4505) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::CartesianProductGenerator10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>' being compiled
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4256): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4256): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4256): error C2955: 'testing::internal::ParamGeneratorInterface' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util.h(142) : see declaration of 'testing::internal::ParamGeneratorInterface'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4258): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4270): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4270): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4275): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4275): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4282): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4282) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::CartesianProductGenerator10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>::Iterator' being compiled
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4282): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4282): error C2955: 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util.h(69) : see declaration of 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4284): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4284): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4320): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4320): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4366): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4366): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4370): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4370): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4456): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4456): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4738): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4766) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::CartesianProductHolder9<Generator1,Generator2,Generator3,Generator4,Generator5,Generator6,Generator7,Generator8,Generator9>' being compiled
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4738): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4738): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4782): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
1>          a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4813) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::CartesianProductHolder10<Generator1,Generator2,Generator3,Generator4,Generator5,Generator6,Generator7,Generator8,Generator9,Generator10>' being compiled
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4782): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>a:\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util-generated.h(4782): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          b:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 2012\vc\include\utility(73) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with VS2012? I am not attached to google test and am not opposed to using a different framework if it works better with VS, I had just heard very good things about gtest.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

VC++ 2012 does not (and will never) support variadic templates; consequently, its standard library implementation attempts to fake them using preprocessor-generated overloads and specializations. As [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2011/09/12/c11-features-in-visual-c-11/) notes, the number of faux variadic template parameters defaults to 5 – the problem is that gtest is trying to instantiate `std::tuple<>` with as many as 10 template arguments.

As the blog post goes on to mention, you can define the `_VARIADIC_MAX` macro project-wide to support up to 10 parameters; you'll probably want to do this by way of your project's [preprocessor definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) setting, but the important thing is to make sure every TU defines it before including any stdlib headers (directly or indirectly).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Trying that out now.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how can I define `_VARIADIC_MAX` project wide? I have a feeling it is under project properties->c++->preprocesor->preprocessor definitions. But I'm not really sure of the syntax.

Comment: @Kyryx : If you click the dropdown arrow for preprocessor definitions, there will be an entry called `<Edit...>` – click that, then add a line that simply has `_VARIADIC_MAX` and hit OK. You'll need to do this for each project configuration (debug/release, x86/x64, etc.).

Comment: I did that, now I get the error `fatal error C1189: #error :  _VARIADIC_MAX must be between 5 and 10, inclusive`

Comment: @Kyryx : Ah, apologies, I forgot our goal was to set it to 10. ;-] Make the line `_VARIADIC_MAX=10`.

Comment: hehe no worries, I really appreciate the help. Its building perfectly now

Answer (score 8):

Rather than modifying the VS2012 tuple implementation using the `_VARIADIC_MAX` macro, I solved this problem by defining the following two macros on the gtest projects and projects including gtest headers:

```
GTEST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE=0
GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=1
```

Setting `GTEST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE` to 0 prevents gtest trying to use the tuple class from the STL headers, and setting `GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE` to 1 instructs gtest to use its own tuple implementation rather than omitting features that require tuple support. I personally preferred this option to tweaking the STL implementation, and this solution should work on any other compilers that have similar problems.

Answer (score 6):

This is fixed in version r675. See https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/detail?r=675

Comment: Still broken at r683.

Answer (score 1):

Also, until you get the latest version, add `GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=0` to your pre-processor definitions.