# GoogleTest enum class not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, googletest

I have the following enum class:

```
enum class Message : qint8 {INFO = 0, WARNING = 1, NON_FATAL_ERROR = 2, FATAL_ERROR = 3, DEBUG_INFO = 4};
```

and when I run the following code with Google Test (checked out from SVN):

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW(
     for(qint32 i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
         logger->onIncomingMessage(mapper::Message::INFO, "Testing logging system")
);
```

The signature of the onIncomingMessage function is:

```
 void onIncomingMessage(const mapper::Message &type, const QString &report);
```

Visual Studio 2012 shows the following exceptions:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > testing::FLAGS_gtest_death_test_style" (?FLAGS_gtest_death_test_style@testing@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) C:\Users\Michele\Projects\occupancymapper\build\Modules\Core\test_logger.obj
    3   IntelliSense: enum "mapper::Message" has no member "INFO"   c:\Users\Michele\Projects\occupancymapper\Modules\Core\test\test_logger.cpp 21
    4   IntelliSense: enum "mapper::Message" has no member "NON_FATAL_ERROR"    c:\Users\Michele\Projects\occupancymapper\Modules\Core\test\test_logger.cpp 30
    5   IntelliSense: enum "mapper::Message" has no member "DEBUG_INFO" c:\Users\Michele\Projects\occupancymapper\Modules\Core\test\test_logger.cpp 40
    6   IntelliSense: enum "mapper::Message" has no member "FATAL_ERROR"    c:\Users\Michele\Projects\occupancymapper\Modules\Core\test\test_logger.cpp 50
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Michele\Projects\occupancymapper\build\Modules\Core\Debug\logger.exe   1
```

Without GoogleTests, the code in my class works fine, but when using GoogleTest, it doesn't. Under Linux, it works perfectly.

I've already applied the VARIADIC_MAX value (set to 10), as suggested here in a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558327/google-test-in-visual-studio-2012?rq=1), but it doesn't work.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use `_VARIADIC_MAX`? You wrote `VARIADIC_MAX` (no underscore). Just to make sure you tried it already

Comment: yes I tried with both, no chance. But this error is not related to Variadic number (i guess)

Comment: Did you try to play with the GTEST_HAS_DEATH_TEST define when compiling GTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue.
In my test-case, I've added this:

```
::testing::FLAGS_gtest_death_test_style = "threadsafe";
```

right after

```
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
```

because under Linux it was giving me problems.

Removing this line under MSVC, solved the issue and then it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

It looks the error has nothing to do with enum class - these are "IntelliSense" (editor code assistance) errors, not compiler's.

The real problem is that linker cannot find "testing::FLAGS_gtest_death_test_style" symbol. Have you specified .lib file to link with? Make you have built the google test library with the same code generation and debug level settings ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533372/4074081) discussion may be helpful).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and let you know

Comment: So I've tried to compile gtest in the same way my application is built. The weird part is that only one test-case (the one calling the function above) is not compiling/is throwing errors, but the other ones aren't. Only the test-case which is using EXPECT_NO_THROW doesn't link.
I'm using CMake and gtest as subproject to be compiled.